# Delphi IDE - Insert text on every selected line (as with vim's block select mode)?

Tags: delphi, ide

In Delphi's IDE (RAD Studio) one can do column/block select like in vim with [Alt+Shift+Arrows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts). This is useful to delete things in a column oriented way, but when inserting text it only gets added to the cursor position, not to the cursor position on every selected line, as one would expect coming from vim. Is there any way to insert text on every selected line or at least to replace a selection with something?

Comment: Note that there is only one cursor position, and not a cursor position on each selected line. But what you want should be possible with search&replace and regular expressions. Just apply the search&replace to only the selected text. Search for the beginning of a line with `^` (AFAIK).

Comment: The problem here is column selection! For a normally selected text one could just copy the selection and use "MultiPaste" to insert some text before each line. I have no idea how one can search for the beginning of each column in search&replace when just a block is selected.

Comment: @Uwe: the same way. Not the beginning of each *column* (you can only select *one* column block), but the beginning of each line. Another way to achieve this (the way I usually do it) is to record a macro and replay it many times. The macro facility is pretty rudimentary, but very fine for this kind of work. Just start the recording with pressing the Home key before adding the text, and moving to the next line before stopping the recording.

Comment: @UweRaabe: what is MultiPaste? Did I miss something?

Comment: IME easiest is to open the source with an external editor. Supply `$EDNAME $SAVE` as tool option parameter, the IDE asks to reload upon return.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I was doing that, but it's not very practical if it has to be done often. I guess I could configure an AutoHotkey script to open the file on vim, but it'd have to be on the current cursor position (line and column) to be practical, otherwise it's still not worth it. If I could get the position to the clipboard somehow that'd solve the issue. Until then I'll use Rudy's solution.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/MultiPaste

Comment: @UweRaabe: Wow, cool, that was new to me. Thanks for the hint.